# Sliding Tab is reloading Fragment after changing Tab

Tags: android, tabs, sliding

Im using these classes for my Tabs:

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java

I have 3 Tabs : Tab1 Tab2 and Tab3.

In Tab3 Im loading contacts from my phone and add them into my ListView.This takes a while till it loaded successfuly (200 contacts).

Now my problem is : When I change my Tab from Tab3 to Tab1 the loading process begins again.So the Fragment is loading from zero again.

So everytime I change to Tab 1  and go back to Tab 3 everything has to be loaded again. Someone got an Idea to find a solution for it ? How can I prevent this Fragment reload ?

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_friends, container, false);

    LV_Contacts = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.LV_Contacts);
    if(adapter_contacts == null)
        new load_contacts().execute();



    return v;
}
```

EDIT: When I change from Tab3 to Tab2 its working fine.It just continues but when I go to Tab1 everything starts from the beginning and it builds the Listview again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you need is to add this

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

for more detail read doc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: Thanks dude ! That was the method I was looking for :)

Comment: Yea the default for a viewpager is the fragment in view, the one before, and the one after. That is why you saw that behavior. It's standard. This solution can be a problem down the line if you decide to rearrange the tabs or add more UI elements/features to a fragment in within the limit and OF COURSE a memory/performance issue if your API Level is low (older device = slower CPU generally) so some users will experience major lag.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Frank. Looks like its something where the developer should take an eye on it ^^